# Show Site Hierarchy in Webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-search-web-part

Is there a way to show a site hierarchy in perhaps a custom web part within SharePoint?  Ideally, I would like the list of links to be updated dynamically when a new subsite is created.

Something simple like a list which showcases where you currently reside within a Site Collection i.e.

**Parent Site**

1. Team Site 1

   - Subsite 1
   - Subsite 2
2. Team Site 2

   - Subsite 1
   - Subsite 2

Could you use a Content Search to achieve this?  Just brainstorming and wanting to see if it is possible to do NOT in the quick launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Keyword filter` in `Content Search Web Part` to `return only sites`

[image]

**But unfortunately,** it will not provide you the desired result as Site Hierarchy.

---

**Alternatively,**  you can use `Table of content` web part that available in Publishing site, **but** it will also show the lists and documents libraries besides the sites and subsites! [here](https://sharepointsharpener.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/quick-fix-remove-libraries-lists-from-toc/) workaround but looks like not working :(

Comment: Hm, this is a good start though.  Thank you!   I've been told to make some page layouts like BrightWork without my company having money to purchase BW :|